# script library using Groovy - SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

Hi there,

I’m starting to work with SOAPUI and Groovy.

I found the reusable code problem. I mean, I would like to avoid having a lot of copies of the same script in different projects.
As I want to make a "global library", how could I do it?

I saw the following method, http://www.spamer.me.uk/wiki/doku.php/soapui_reusable_script_library?rev=1350558275 but I have some doubts. Would it be the only way to do it?

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a JAR with your code and put it to bin/ext in your soapui directory (for example C:/Program%20Files/SmartBear/soapUI-Pro-3.0-beta-2/bin/ext/sqljdbc.jar ) so it will be added to soapui classpath

Comment: I'm triying to do it using the scripts folder (according to http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html), but it works just with the example script. Have you tried this way? I'll try your solution anyway. thanks :)

Comment: I did! thanks for your help. the other way worked at the end. 
could you give some advice to code an (global).groovy for the next assert:
assert messageExchange.responseStatusCode == 200 
and then, to use it through the project? 

:)