# SoapUI defining a library of reusable methods

Tags: groovy, soapui, test-runner

I'm running into copy-pasting a lot of code at the moment in my SoapUI projects, and thought I'd have some sort of library of helper functions that can carry out most of my tasks.

So I have a test suite for this, and the code itself is in a Groovy Script test step in this test suite. The idea is that I make my helper methods available to the context I'm in (a REST test request step).

It instantiates fine and all that, but the problem is that when I want to invoke `run(testRunner, context)`, I am not having access to the `testRunner` property. I've read something about that this is how it is.

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [script library using Groovy - SOAPUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075187/script-library-using-groovy-soapui)

Comment: not a duplicate as the OP is not asking how to create a script library but rather how to access the testRunner object where it doesn't exist. He needs the testRunner object to access the script library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the same method as you for script library. I used the method described by Kerry Doan at http://www.doan.me/script-library-in-soapui-free.aspx

When i tried to access this script library from project load script i did not have access to the testRunner so i created the testRunner object and as i did not have access to the context object i had to create that too.

Check out the code below.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext

//to create the testRunner object I need a testCase object and a new StringToObjectMap
//I initially used the test case in the script library but as i needed the 
//testRunner object to the test case being executed so i created the object to
//the test case being executed.
//I did not want to worry about test suite or test case names so i used their index 
//assuming that there will be at least one test suite and at least one test case when
//this script is run
testCase = project.getTestSuiteAt(0).getTestCaseAt(0)
tcRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner( testCase, new StringToObjectMap() );

//A context is essentially a WsdlTestRunContext object and as you can see below all i 
//have done to create that is pass it a test step object which was obtained by using index
//rather than name.
tStep = testCase.getTestStepAt(0)
tcContext = new WsdlTestRunContext(tStep)

//my script library is in a seperate project called `Script Library` and all the 
//groovy scripts are in a test suite called `Script Library`
scripts = project.workspace.projects["Script Library"].testSuites["Script Library"];
scripts.testCases["Scripts"].testSteps["runTest"].run(tcRunner, tcContext);
```

Comment: @Abhishek Asthana  Thanks it helped. I created  `tcRunner` in script assertion of a step in test case. Later realized that `tcRunner` is not valid in any other test case. Any idea, how can we modularize the creation of `tcRunner`.Using the link you provided,  I am passing `tcRunner` like this from script assertion `context.searchChange.search("value1","value2",tcRunner)`. `search` is a method in my test library which utilizes `tcRunner`.

Comment: It has been a while since I did this, try creating the tcRunner object at a higher hierarchy of the test case instead of the assertions step. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? It would be great if you can create a separate question for your problem as it would help other searching for solutions to the same problem as you.