# null object error when calling code from script assertion - soapui (creating test Runner in script assertion)

Tags: groovy, soapui

In a soapui groovy script test step I've this.

```
context.setProperty("searchA", new searchA());
class searchA{

    def testRunner
    def searchA(testRunner){
        this.testRunner=testRunner
        }

    def search(a,b){

        def search_TestCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Search")
          search_TestCase.setPropertyValue("ABC", a)
          search_TestCase.setPropertyValue("DEF", b)
          search_TestCase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)

        }
    }
```

and in an assertion script in a different test suite I am calling the above code like this.

```
scripts = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Test"]
scripts.testCases["Lib123"].testSteps["TestLib123"].run(context.getTestRunner(),context)
context.searchA.search("value1","value2")
```

but this gives me error `"can not get property testCase on null object".` whats wrong here?

Comment: `messageExchange.modelItem.testStep` is null

Comment: @tim_yates  Its not null. On giving a `log.info` statement I get `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep@6078498`

Comment: Have a read through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to find out what **all** we need to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing null object error now. The issue was that `testRunner` is not available in script assertion so we need to create it like this in script assertion and then pass it in the caller method.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext

testCase = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase
tcRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner( testCase, new StringToObjectMap() );

context.searchA.search("value1","value2",tcRunner)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760902/soapui-defining-a-library-of-reusable-methods) thread helped me.